# SpringMVC based Rest Service - StackOverflowError when path is not defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm creating a project using the `@RestController` annotation of Spring 4. Everything is working fine, when I call a URL path that is configured I receive a well formatted answer or an error if something happened.

But, if I call a service in a path that is not defined, I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:592)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:592)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:592)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
```

I know this error is happening because my request could not be mapped to a resource, but I'm wondering why I am not getting a `404 - Not found` error type?

My DispatcherServlet is configured like this:

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = 
            servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1); 
dispatcher.addMapping("/");
```

This is a sample of my Service classes:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Genotypes")
public class GenotypeService {

... @Autowired objects here ...    

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Genotype> findGenotypesLike(@RequestParam(value="genName", required=false) String name, @RequestParam(value="like", defaultValue="false") Boolean like){
    if(name == null){
        return genotypeBO.findAllGenotypes();
    }
    return genotypeBO.findByName(name, like);
}
```

If I call `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/Genotypes` I get my response but if I call `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/SomethingNotMapped` the exception is thrown and the error code at the browser side is a `500 - Internal Server Error`

By the way, my application is running on Apache Tomcat v7.0.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Which exact version of Tomcat do you use?

Comment: I use version 7.0.57